# I have more than 20 paper wallets with very little bitcoin in them. How can I combine all of them together?

Tags: paper-wallet, sweep, transaction-fees

I have a bunch of paper wallets with different small amounts of Bitcoin in them. How can I combine them all into one address without having to pay a fee for sending each paper wallet to my own account? How to do a bulk send and pay a one time fee that would be cheap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to be sure that the fees you gonna pay to transfer those bitcoin is inferior than the amount each have, then you can import all your private keys using a service like Blockchain.info "My Wallet service". Once done you will have a new wallet with all your old paper wallet merged

A more privacy method using bitcoind is available here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys

Answer (score 4):

You should import all the private keys and not sweep them.
Wallets like blockchain.info has this function where it will import the private key. In that case the private key will become part of the new wallet.

Import all the private keys into a new wallet. Thats it ! During spending the wallet will combine inputs from your private keys to spend required amount.

Answer (score 3):

You need to

1. [Import the keys into a wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys).
2. Send the imported bitcoin to a new address.

Here is a way to do it with [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download):

1. Make sure the Blockchain is downloaded and fully synced (can take days and requires 100s GB of free space for a fresh install).
2. Open the console by going to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Debug window</kbd> → <kbd>Console</kbd>
3. Import all but the last key by typing `importprivkey "key" "label" false`
   Replace `key` with the key, and `label` with a name for the paper wallet. `false` tells it not to rescan the blockchain for your keys. We want to rescan, but it takes a long time so we'll do it once at the end.
4. For the last key, type `true` instead of `false`: `importprivkey "key" "label" true`
   It should now scan the entire blockchain for any transactions involving your keys. This will take minutes, possibly hours.
5. Close the Debug window. Your wallet should now show the imported balance and also the incoming transactions from when the bitcoin was sent to the paper wallets.
6. Now you can go to the <kbd>Send</kbd> screen and send the bitcoin to a new address. If you are going to spend the entire wallet balance, you can finish at this step. If you have other bitcoin in your wallet and want to make sure it's the paper wallets' addresses you are spending from, see below.

Selecting specific keys to spend from:

1. Enable coin control features:
   <kbd>Options/Preferences/Settings</kbd> menu → <kbd>Wallet</kbd> → Make sure <kbd>Enable coin control features</kbd> is checked.
2. Close the Options window and go to <kbd>Send</kbd> → <kbd>Inputs...</kbd>
3. You should now be able to select the imported addresses according to the `label`s you specified when importing them.

Answer (score 0):

If its less then the transaction fees (Bitcoin Dust) transferring them all to one wallet will take time.

If the wait time is too long or never goes through you can start using the wallets (start with the wallet with the fewest number of bitcoin) to store new incoming bitcoins and work your way up the ladder, Just make sure to transfer the maximum amount out of the wallet so you can end this cycle of bitcoin dust.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a way. You could send all of the bitcoins in each wallet to one address without any transaction fees if you are prepared to wait potentially a long time for it to be confirmed.